# Trying to implement a page object model in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following class,

```
class login:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
       
    def open_page(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        print("You have logged in")
```

And I have a test file that uses this class

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from TestingProject.Pages.login_page import login
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def test_login(driver):
    login_page = login(driver)
    login_page.open_page('https://www.bbc.co.uk/news')
    time`enter code here`.sleep(10)
```

When running the test file a browser opens very quickly and closes immediately, no errors are thrown, not sure what's happening here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it works fine with the following example

```
class login:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
       
    def open_page(self, url):
        print("Start")
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        print("You have logged in")
```

Run file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from TestingProject.Pages.login_page import login
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
def test_login(driver):
    login_page = login(driver)
    login_page.open_page('https://www.google.com/')
test_login(driver)
```

Comment: Really appreciate that, made a few changes to what you posted and it worked namely the chrome driver path.

Comment: Really appreciate that, made a few changes to what you posted and it worked namely the chrome driver path. How would I create a method to find element by xpath?

Comment: If you are using the latest Selenium (at least 4.6+), you no longer need to define the executable path. https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager.